# How to find inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{\sqrt{s} \sqrt{a+s}}{b+s}$

Tags: laplace-transform

How to find inverse Laplace transform of

$$\frac{\sqrt{s} \sqrt{a+s}}{b+s}$$

where $a$ and $b$ constants, ${a,b}>0$

I tried to solve it, but I couldn't.

**EDITED.**

Numerical solution for $a=1,b=1$.
Plot:
[image]

Comment: It have to satisfy $\lim_{s\to\infty}F(s)=0$.

Comment: Why do you need to find it and what are your actual attempts? It has a distributional part due to MyGlasses' remark.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio ,I tried with  convolution teorem,but checking numericall dosen;t work.,I tried with expanding with infinite sum,but could not find closed sum.I tried with Bromwich Integral ,but I not succeed....,I tried with Mellin Transform, but could not find inverse..

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. Mathematica ,Maple can't  find solution.I searched in the Tables but I not succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method of consideration may be applied to the following. By using the series expansion
$$\sqrt{1-x} = 1 - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2k-2)! \, x^{k}}{2^{2k-1} \, k! \, (k-1)!}.$$
Now the fraction in question becomes:
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{s \, (s+a)}}{s+b} &= \frac{\sqrt{\left(s+ \frac{a}{2}\right)^{2} - \frac{a^{2}}{4}}}{s+b} = \frac{s + \frac{a}{2}}{s+b} \cdot \sqrt{1 - \frac{a^{2}}{4 \, \left(s + \frac{a}{2}\right)^{2}}} \\
&= \frac{s + \frac{a}{2}}{s+b} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2k-2)! \, \left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{2k}}{2^{2k-1} \, k! \, (k-1)!} \cdot \frac{1}{(s+b) \, \left(s + \frac{a}{2}\right)^{2k-1}}.
\end{align}
By using the convolution theorem it is developed into:
\begin{align}
\frac{(2k-2)!}{(s+b) \, \left(s + \frac{a}{2}\right)^{2k-1}} &\Doteq \int_{0}^{t} e^{-b (t-u)} \, u^{2k-2} \, e^{- \frac{a u}{2}} \, du \\
&\Doteq \frac{e^{-bt}}{\left(\frac{a}{2} - b\right)^{2k-1}} \, \int_{0}^{\left(\frac{a}{2} - b\right) \, t} e^{-x} \, x^{2k-2} \, dx \\
&\Doteq \frac{e^{-bt}}{\left(\frac{a}{2} -b\right)^{2k-1}} \, \gamma\left(2k-1, \left(\frac{a}{2} - b\right) \, t \right), 
\end{align} 
where $\gamma(a,x)$ is the incomplete Gamma function. Putting all the components together yields
$$\frac{\sqrt{s \, (s+a)}}{s+b} \Doteq \delta(t) + \left(\frac{a}{2} - b\right) \, e^{-b t} \, \left[1 - 2 \, \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(\frac{a}{2 \, (a-2b)}\right)^{2k} \, \gamma\left(2k-1, \left(\frac{a}{2} -b\right) \, t \right) }{ k! \, (k-1)!} \right]. $$

Notice that if $b = \frac{a}{2}$ then this reduces to
$$\frac{\sqrt{s \, (s+a)}}{s+\frac{a}{2}} \Doteq \delta(t) - \frac{a^{2} \, t}{8} \, e^{- \frac{a \, t}{2}} \, {}_{1}F_{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}; \frac{3}{2} , 2; \frac{a^{2} \, t^{2}}{16} \right).$$

Comment: Yours answer is wrong.If I put $a=1,b=1,t=1$ in yours formuła I get $Infinity$.It should be approximately: $-0.2443072$.I checked numericall in Mathematica.

Comment: I corrected yours mistake and Yours answer is useful to me.It should be:$\delta (t)+\left(\frac{a}{2}-b\right) \exp (-b t)-\exp (-b t) \sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{4^{-k} a^{2 k} (a-2 b)^{1-2 k} \left(\Gamma
   (-1+2 k)-\Gamma \left(-1+2 k,\frac{1}{2} (a-2 b) t\right)\right)}{k! \Gamma (k)}$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Good catch of the error. Starting with an incorrect term in the convolution leads to an extension of said error.